How to use a context manager to create an instance of a class?
I want to create a class that makes use of requests.Session(). Because of this, I want to use a context manager. However, when I try to access any of the functions or variables of the class, the context manager replies:
exception type:  <class 'AttributeError'>
exception value:  type object 'NoneType' has no attribute 'user'
exception trace:  <traceback object at 0x0000024CFAF30340>

My code:
Class request_session:
    def __init__(self, user="rwelch"):
        self.user = user
        self.session = (
            requests.Session()
        ) 

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Creating a new connection...")

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_val, trace):
        print("Closing connection...")
        if exception_type:
            print(
                "exception type: ",
                exception_type,
                "\nexception value: ",
                exception_val,
                "\nexception trace: ",
                trace,
            )
            response = True
        else:
            response = False
        self.session.close()
        return response

...
with request_session() as request_session_handler:
   print(request_session_handler.user)

This type of implementation I got from examples using exclusively file management, so I'm sure there's something fundamental I'm missing here.
Thanks in advance

return self.session in __enter__.

@MarkTolonen return self, but this worked, thanks!

Oops, right, you want the whole object to access .user.

you should return the value of the session handler, otherwise it'll return None implicitly, leading to the error you see
>>> def test():
...     """ implicitly returns None """
...     pass  # does nothing
... 
>>> test().user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

alternatively, you can often avoid creating a custom context manager and decorate a function with @contextlib.contextmanager and yield from it
class Foo:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.managed_resource = bar()
        return self.managed_resource
    def __exit__(self):
        self.managed_resource.close()

@contextlib.contextmanager
def my_contextmgr():
    resource = bar()
    try:
        yield resource
    finally:
        resource.close()


return self worked for me, thank you!
